# AsNoTracking method throwing error in linq statement

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

Below is my query to get information from the database. For the performance point of view, I want to use `AsNoTracking` method on my entities.

```
var teamrole = (from role in _context.USERROLEs.AsNoTracking()
    from team in _context.TEAMROLEs.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ID == role.ROLEID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from queue in _context.WORKQUEUEs.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.ID == team.QUEID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where team.ROLECD == roleCode
    select new { team, queue }).ToList();
```

Here is my context look like:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ZTEAMROLE> ZTEAMROLEs { get; set; }    
    //Some other entities here...
}
```

Entities:

```
[Table("TEAMROLE")]
public partial class TEAMROLE
{
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string ID { get; set; }  

    [StringLength(36)]
    public string QUEID { get; set; }

    //More Properties...
}
```

The error I am getting while executing a query `teamrole`

> Method
>   `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[XXX.Entities.TEAMROLE] AsNoTracking()` declared on type
>   `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[XXX.Entities.TEAMROLE]`
>   cannot be called with instance of type
>   `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery'1[XXX.Entities.TEAMROLE]`

Comment: You only need to call `AsNoTracking` once. Based on the Exception message, the query, and the DbContext type, you have a conversion to an in memory representation of the collection in property `_context.TEAMROLEs`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have to call `.AsNoTracking` once on the query, not on each `DbSet<T>`:

```
var teamrole = (from role in _context.USERROLEs
    from team in _context.TEAMROLEs.Where(x => x.ID == role.ROLEID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from queue in _context.WORKQUEUEs.Where(x => x.ID == team.QUEID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where team.ROLECD == roleCode
    select new { team, queue })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: NOTE: In order to use .AsNoTracking, what you select has to be a reference type (as it is in this example).  If you are selecting into, say, a List<int> (so, for example, if the select here was `select team.QUEID`, then it won't build.  To fix, simply create a new object: `select new {team.QUEID}` and then after .AsNoTracking, project to your value type `.Select(x=>x.QUEID)`